# How do I give "Project Web access" in Dynamics AX Server in Windows Server 2003?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, axapta

I'm trying install Dynamics AX Server 2009 in Windows Server 2003 but I have got problem with this. They tell me I have to give "Project Web access" but I don`t know what is it? Can you help me?

[image]

What I have to put as the project web access URL?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably exactly what the error says.

> "Dynamics" is not a valid Microsoft Office Project Server database.

You're missing MS Project Server, which is a prerequisite.  This is why you don't have a URL to put in or a database to connect to.  You simply haven't installed it.  The actual error is because you aren't connecting to the database.

[image]

Comment: I can have database in this same virtual machine but I don`t know what I have to put there for example http://localhost:610/Sample/

Comment: You're confusing me.  If you login to SQL, you should see a "Dynamics" database, which is what the AX AOS connects to.  Microsoft Project has its own separate database.  It looks like you need to just point to the project database...where did you install it?  See here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms513875(v=office.12).aspx where it says:
"All Project Server data is stored in Microsoft SQL Server databases, which can be located on separate servers."

Comment: I understand your point but I want to prepare this only for test I added new image which can help to understand my question much more then now.

Comment: You need to put the web access URL.  It sounds like you haven't installed MS Project Server at all.  You need to install MS Project server, which will create a database and a web access URL.  Then you install the AX sync proxy and service, and point it AT the installed instance of Project Server.  The default URLs are here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms413710(v=office.12).aspx but they can be anything.  It's whatever you set it up as.

Comment: FafalPolandBeginner...you need to install MS Project Server.  You can not move forward until this is complete.  At all.